# How to show uploaded photo Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im new in ruby, here u can find my code: https://bitbucket.org/Messeir/reddit
I used carrierwave gem for uploading photos. Unfortunatelly i dont know how to show uploaded photo on main site near to submited links?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few thoughts.

The photo is uploaded. We're assuming that it'll land on the file system of your server somewhere.

After you receive the file upload, as a prototype, try to move the file in the Rails root "public/images" directory. On your page, you could try an image tag as such:

If that works, you can tell at least that your "file-upload-save-to-disk" operation is working.

In a second phase, save the file somewhere else, say in a /data/images directory. Create a controller that will respond to a /mycontroller/myimage?... url, an in that method, respond with the image content.

That's pretty rough but it's a start. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: file upload operation is working. Unfortunatelly second part i dont know how to do